# Convert nested dict to dataframe, syntax error?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

##### Problem

I am converting multiple nested dicts to dataframes. I have a slightly different dict that I haven't been able to convert to a dataframe using my attempted solution. I am providing a shortened copy of my dict with dummy values as the reprex.

##### Reprex dict:

```
{'metrics': [{'metric': 'DatasetCorrelationsMetric',
   'result': {'current': {'stats': {'pearson': {'target_prediction_correlation': None,
       'abs_max_features_correlation': 0.1},
      'cramer_v': {'target_prediction_correlation': None,
       'abs_max_features_correlation': None}}},
    'reference': {'stats': {'pearson': {'target_prediction_correlation': None,
       'abs_max_features_correlation': 0.7},
      'cramer_v': {'target_prediction_correlation': None,
       'abs_max_features_correlation': None}}}}}]}
```

##### My attempted solution

Code is based on similar dict wrangling problems that I had, but I am not sure how to apply it for this specific dict.

```
data = {}
for result in reprex_dict['metrics']:
    data[result['result']] = {
        **{f"ref_{key}": val for key, val in result['result']['reference'].items()},
        **{f"cur_{key}": val for key, val in result['result']['current'].items()}
    }
```

##### Expected dataframe format:

| cur_pearson_target_prediction_correlation | cur_pearson_abs_max_features_correlation | cur_cramer_v_target_prediction_correlation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| None | 0.1 | None |

##### Error message

I am currently getting this error too.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [403], line 7
      5 data = {}
      6 for result in corr_matrix_dict['metrics']:
----> 7     data[result['result']] = {
      8         **{f"ref_{key}": val for key, val in result['result']['reference']['stats'].items()},
      9         **{f"cur_{key}": val for key, val in result['result']['current']['stats'].items()}
     10     }

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: problem is in ur data[result['result']]. your key is a dictionary which u cannot do that

Comment: Right, but I don't understand how to access the 'stats' key from the beginning.

Comment: the problem here is how you are defining the keys in data. 
the second part works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the `TypeError` is due `result['result']` (which is a dictionary) not being usable as a key. If you used some thing [like `result['metric']`] then the error would no longer be raised, but I think that the [resulting structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlHHE.png) is not the outcome you want.

For flattening nested data, I often take a recursive approach. Below is a simplified version of my [`flattenObj`](https://pastebin.com/v3Fep60B) function:

```py
def flattenDict(orig:dict, kList=[], kSep='_', rename={}):
    if not isinstance(orig, dict): return [(kList, orig)]
    tList, dCt = [], len([v for v in orig.values() if isinstance(v,dict)])
    for k, v in orig.items():
        kli = kList + ([] if isinstance(v,dict) and dCt==1 else [str(k)])
        tList += flattenDict(v, kli, None)
    if not isinstance(kSep, str): return tList
    return {kSep.join([rename.get(k,k) for k in kl]):v for kl,v in tList}
```

---

```py
# import pandas as pd
nrMap = {'current':'cur','reference':'ref'}
rows = [flattenDict(result, rename=nrMap) for result in reprex_dict['metrics']]
rowsDf = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

> | `rows` |
> | --- |
>
> ```py
> [{'metric': 'DatasetCorrelationsMetric',
>   'cur_pearson_target_prediction_correlation': None,
>   'cur_pearson_abs_max_features_correlation': 0.1,
>   'cur_cramer_v_target_prediction_correlation': None,
>   'cur_cramer_v_abs_max_features_correlation': None,
>   'ref_pearson_target_prediction_correlation': None,
>   'ref_pearson_abs_max_features_correlation': 0.7,
>   'ref_cramer_v_target_prediction_correlation': None,
>   'ref_cramer_v_abs_max_features_correlation': None}]
> ```
>
> ---
>
> | `rowsDf.T` [Transposed to fit better] |
> | --- |
> | [image: opdf] |

---

If you don't want the `metric` column, you can either [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) it or [omit it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rtst8.png) by defining `rows` as

```py
rows = [flattenDict(result['result'], rename=nrMap) for result in reprex_dict['metrics']]
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you for sharing your approach too as I am learning how to wrangle dicts.